# When do we need to use the 'Compose' option in Form Recognizer Labelling Tool?

Tags: azure-form-recognizer

The v2.1 preview of Azure Form Recognizer Labeling tool which is recently published has a feature to compose models, When do we need to use is? Can anyone explain me some usecase for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently it's recommended to build one model for each form type in custom form. Model compose allows you to compose up to 100 models, hence one analyze call can process many type of forms - form type classification will be done automatically for you.

Comment: So in order to use this feature we need to make seperate projects for seperate models,Am I right?

Comment: Yes, each model (form type) is a project and then you compose all the models to a single model compose.

Comment: What's supposed to send in body for this request? I tried json array with model ids but no luck